# Python- how can I set the value for params from another file

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have to edit some test I have.
I have a file which inclused all the details for a test I have to execute. The file name for example is "test 1"

In this file there are few global params:

```
LINK_IP_ADDR = "10.8.22.89"
STABILITY_SLEEP = 5  
MAIN_STATE_SLEEP = 30
```

For making the tests automaticly and generic I want to set the the value from the params from another python file (for example config_file). How should I do it?

Comment: When you say "another file", do you mean another python program?

Comment: If this file is just a text file (and not part of project) you need to read text from file and seperate that text according to your format for instance: Read 1 line 'LINK_IP_ADDR = "10.8.22.89"', check if like starts with "LINK_IP_ADDR". If it does, it's an IP address, so skip the '=' sign and read the text between quotation marks. Parse the text as IP whereever it should be.
Just to clarify, there is no 1 specific command to do this. You have to write the logic to process each parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use configuration files for this. The [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) package would do the job.
If you want a quick and dirty version, the following could be for you.

In your 'test files', write the following:

```
class Params:
    LINK_IP_ADDR = "10.8.22.89"
    STABILITY_SLEEP = 5
    MAIN_STATE_SLEEP = 30
```

Then in your main program you import the parameters you want and just use them:

```
from test1 import Params
# from test2 import Params
print Params.LINK_IP_ADDR
```

You can then switch your import statements to the file you want to use. I would use a normal .ini file with different sections though.

Comment: @Schore- I want to import the params from the config files (to write over the values in the test files)

Comment: That is what my example does. Define a Params class in each config file and then just import the one you want.

Comment: @Schore- I put the "class Params: in config_test.py and the second part in my main test. I got the following error- name 'STABILITY_SLEEP' is not defined

Comment: If you wrote 'from config_test import Params then you have to write Params.STABILITY_SLEEP in your main test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick n' dirty way from a plain file:

```
params = dict()

with open('config_file') as f:
    for line in f:
        param, value = line.split("=")
        params[param.strip()] = value.strip()

print(params)
```

config_file:

```
LINK_IP_ADDR = "10.8.22.89"
STABILITY_SLEEP = 5
MAIN_STATE_SLEEP = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

for config file i used .yaml file. This format stores your config like json or python-dict. U can store complex structure (array, hashmap, ...) very good

config.yaml

```
LINK_IP_ADDR: 10.8.22.89
STABILITY_SLEEP: 5 
MAIN_STATE_SLEEP: 30
```

another.py

```
import yaml
configs = yaml.safe_load(file("path_to_config.yaml"))
# to use you configs:
configs['LINK_IP_ADDR']
#.....
```